# How to add a favicon to a Next.js static site?

Tags: favicon, next.js, static-site

I'm trying to add a favicon to a Next.js static site without much luck.

I've tried customising the document with components from `'next/document'`
https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document

A straight link to the favicon.ico file doesn't work because the file isn't included in the build and the href doesn't update to `/_next/static/...`

Importing the image and adding to the link's href doesn't work either (see commented out lines).

```js
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

// import favicon from '../data/imageExports';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {/* <link rel="shortcut icon" href={favicon} /> */}
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/icons/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

**The favicon links get added however it doesn't display.** I'd expect it to work when I import the file, but it just adds a `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="[object Object]">` link.

Has anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

1. Create a `/static` folder in project root. This will be added to the static export folder.
2. Add favicon file in `/static` folder.
3. Add `_document.js` to `/pages/` folder according to [documentation (nextjs.org)](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) or [documentation (github.com)](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-document).
4. Add `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />` to head.
5. `npm run build && npm run export`

P.S. Thanks to the [previous answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEKzt.png) that was deleted. It works!

---

Edit: Another way is to do this is to *import Head* into your root layout and add the link there. Anything added to *Head* gets inserted into the document head tag.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

const Page = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    // Other layout/components
  </div>
);

export default Page;
```

**Update :**

The static directory has been deprecated in favor of the public directory. [Doc](https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/static-dir-deprecated)

So, the code would now look like

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

const Page = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    // Other layout/components
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Documentation link now here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document or https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-document

Comment: although this works, now next.js favours `/public` folder rather than `/static`  https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/static-dir-deprecated.md

Comment: Why'd you reject their edit just to reapply the changes? Also, I can confirm the answer was deleted; I added a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEKzt.png) for future reference.

Comment: @S.S.Anne That was a misclick for Tesseracter's edit, the edit was good - my apologies for that, so I rolled it back. Regarding the deleted answer, I don't know why that person deleted it, that solution worked then.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it displayed React Favicon Logo and kept loading. All I've done is adding `..`, so it would be: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/favicon.ico" />`.
P.S: I am using a version prior to `9.0.6` that's why I still use `static` public directory.

Thanks @AdvaitJunnarkar!

Comment: when i move faricon or static file into public file, it didnt work anymore

Comment: the documentation did it for me

Comment: When using a basePath, is it supposed to work with the public folder ? I have a basePath, my `favicon.ico` is in the public folder and I defined it like that `<link rel='shortcut icon' href='/favicon.ico' />` but the link stay without my basePath like that in my browser : `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">`

Comment: how do we do that if we're using app router instead of pages?

Comment: As of 2023, Next13, simply adding the favicon to the public/ folder worked

Answer (score 72):

Simply add your favicon.ico in public folder,
Next js will automatically take that favicon for all pages.

No need to add any favicon link to any pages or in  tag no need to add link for favicon.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/static-dir-deprecated.md

Comment: Thank you! All I need is only replace the current favicon.ico on public folder. Using next v10.0.2

Comment: the best answer!

Comment: This problem with this though is the formats are wrong since there needs to be atleast 24 favicon assets?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, simply added ico file to /public and boom!

Comment: Assets in public folder can be accessed by browsers. Tour browser will look for the favicon.ico file, not Next. However, if you don't a link there are issues with mobile and tablet. Especially when someone tries to save a link to their app launcher, the icon won't use the favicon.

Comment: Need to be inside "public/images" folder with Next.js 18.

Answer (score 45):

The accepted answer is nice, but might be worth pointing out that you *don't have* to modify `_document.js` for adding a favicon (nor for adding any tags to `head`).

I found out for myself that placing favicon in `_app.js` makes more sense. This file is most likely to exist already for setting up a layout for the pages or something like this. And you can add `Head` tag *literally anywhere* (see [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#populating-head))

So I ended up with `_app.js`

```
class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not working for me, the only way which works is that i put faricon into static folder

Comment: You can store your favicon in wherever you want, this question is about how to add it to a website, not where to locate the file. So probably you just specified wrong path to your favicon.

Answer (score 23):

As of June 2020, you don't have to add/edit the `document.js` or `_head.js` files. All you need do to is place the `favicon.ico` file inside the `public` directory and that's it.

Comment: I've added "favicon.ico" into folder public but when I run build I don't see the favicon be  compiled inside folder .next. Do you have an example? Thanks you.

Comment: It doesn't get put into any other folder, you just leave it in the public folder. If it's there, nextjs picks it up and uses it. I'm using next@9.4.4.

Comment: I'm using next@9.4.4 either. but still got the same problem :(

Comment: I'm using Next 9.5.0, I placed the favicon.ico file inside public directory and voila it worked!! thanks @AndresZapata

Answer (score 22):

**Only adding .ico file is not enough.**

It is not enough as the default.ico file will be used only by desktop browsers. You need to support different devices like tables, smartphones, etc. By adding different sizes the app could be stored on smartphone desktop.

Add link tags to `<Head>` section in `_document.jsx` or `_document.tsx` The question is only about .ico file, but I would recommend to add different dimensions and formats for better support.

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript, DocumentContext, DocumentInitialProps } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render(): React.ReactElement {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/site.webmanifest" />
          <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffc40d" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

You can generate different icons using [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) and upload results to `/public/favicons/` folder. This folder can be referenced by `/favicons/` due to nature of [public directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Comment: Thx a lot. It's to much code for one favicon, I think, but your solution helped

Comment: The only right answer; since you need 24 favicons at least to be complient across devices.

Comment: This wont' work in next 12, they got rid of PNG and SVG loaders

Comment: @serraosays Could you please share the link to doc mentioning that? I am running Next 12.1 and don't have any issues with this configuration.

Comment: @Black - docs on new Next compiler: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler. They're kind of forcing you to use next/image now. I haven't found a way to load jpg, png, etc without custom webpack 5 loaders (which implies they dropped those loaders from the default). Would love to be wrong about this, it's a pain right now.

Comment: Also worth reviewing - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/26167

Answer (score 6):

I had to do favicon.src to make it work

Doesn't work:

```
import favicon from '...'
...

<link rel="shortcut icon" href={favicon} />
```

Works:

```
import favicon from '...'
...

<link rel="shortcut icon" href={favicon.src} />
```

To figure this out, I ran `console.log(favicon)` and it turns out that it was an object that looks something like this:

```
{
  height: 16,
  src: "path/to/favicon.603d046c.ico"
  width: 16,
}
```

Answer (score 6):

May 2023/NextJS 13 Update:

Add a `favicon.ico` to your `/app` folder. NextJS will automatically generate the appropriate code in the `<head>` for it.

You can also add `icon.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|svg)`, or `apple-icon.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)` file to the root segment.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons

Answer (score 5):

### In my case it DID NOT WORK WITH OUT THE IMPORT:

file: _app.tsx

```
    import { AppContext, AppProps } from "next/app";
    import "../styles/common.scss";
    import Head from 'next/head';
    //For me it didn't work without the following import...
    import favico from "../static/favicon.ico";
    
    
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
      const csrfToken = pageProps["anti-csrftoken-a2z"];
      return (
        <div>
          <Head>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href={favico} type="image/x-icon" />
          </Head>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }: AppContext) => {
      let pageProps = {};
      if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
      }
      return { pageProps };
    };
    
    export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called
> `public` in the root directory. Files inside `public` can then be
> referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).
>
> For example, if you add an image to `public/me.png`, the following code
> will access the image:
>
> ```
> import Image from 'next/image'
>
> function Avatar() {   
>     return <Image src="/me.png" alt="me" width="64" height="64" />
> }
>
> export default Avatar
> ```
>
> Note: `next/image` requires Next.js 10 or later.
>
> This folder is also useful for `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, Google
> Site Verification, and any other static files (including `.html`)!

For your case, if you just replace the `favicon.ico` it will update accordingly.

For more details visit the official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Answer (score 3):

### Next JS App Router, Pages Router v13+

For some reason favicon isn't working if the file name is the same as default (i.e `favicon.ico`) after some combinations, changing the name to `icon.ico` worked in both the routers ✅

### App Router

1. Delete default vercel icon ( `favicon.ico` )
2. Add your custom favicon with file name ( `icon.ico` ) in `/app` directory

### Pages Router

1. Add your custom favicon with file name ( `icon.ico` ) in `/public` directory
2. Add `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icon.ico"></link>` in `_document.js`

```js
<Html lang="en">
  <Head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icon.ico"></link>
  </Head>
  <body>
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
  </body>
</Html>
```

> PS: deleting of default `favicon.ico` (vercel favicon) is not required in pages router, but do delete if not used

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#image-files-ico-jpg-png)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be useful for someone

```
<Head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-167x167.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="128x128" href="/favicons/favicon-128x128.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="/favicons/favicon-196x196.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicons/mstile-144x144.png"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/favicons/mstile-70x70.png"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/favicons/mstile-150x150.png"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-square144x144logo" content="/favicons/mstile-144x144.png"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/favicons/mstile-310x310.png"/>
</Head>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to put mine under `public/images` directory with Next.js v18.
Putting under `public` did not work.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Next.js v18 (April 2023)

Answer (score 1):

This confused me too, but it's actually really simple.

You just need to —

1. add your `favicon.ico` file to `/public/assets/favicon.ico`.
2. somewhere in your code, you need to add the favicon into your page `<head>` like —

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

<Head>
    ... the rest of your HTML head ...
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> // <- HERE
</Head>
```

I wrote more about this here — [Favicons in NextJS | MONN blog](https://monn.app/blog/favicon-and-nextjs-how-to-add-a-favicon-to-nextjs-website) — if you're after something a bit more in-depth. I also go over my usual go-to method of creating a `<HeadMetaTags />` to encapsulate all this.

Answer (score 1):

(Updated answer for Next.js 13 as of June 2023)

1. Add to /pages/_document.js (or use the new /app router structure if you have migrated to that from /pages)

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#image-files-ico-jpg-png

Docs say to add to _app.js but _document.js works as well.

This is my /pages_document.js file for a working example:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        
        // Here is where you add the link to the favicon
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

1. Place your favicon files in /public

I made a folder inside of /public called "favicon" so the path to the file you will link to in the above code example is /public/favicon/favicon.io.

If you drop your favicon.io files in /public without creating a subfolder just update the link in the example to /public/favicon.io instead.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Next.js 14.1. Per the documentation I put `favicon.ico` in the root of the `/app` directory but I could not get it to display in the browser. I also tried moving it to `/public/images` and `/public/img` with no luck.

Changing the name from `favicon.ico` to `icon.ico` and keeping it in the `/app` directory solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was missing in production site but working fine in local because I didn't add the public folder in the artifacts of the production site. I assumed that next.js would put all it needs in .next folder but it's not the case.

```
cp -R ./.next/ artifacts/
cp -R ./node_modules/ artifacts
cp -R ./public/ artifacts  #missing line in my github action code
cp package.json ./artifacts/package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might come from the `ico` format. For some reason it needs to be inside an `images` folder within the public directory for the favicon to work with this format.
Whereas when I tried using an `svg` and a `png` it worked even if the files are located at the root of the `public` directory (not within any `images` folder).

In both cases though, as it was indicated above, it seems that you will need to specify the new favicon path in the `_document.tsx` file inside the `<Head />` component from `next/document`.

Either of the following worked for me:

```
<Head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
</Head>
```

Or

```
<Head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.svg" />
</Head>
```

The `svg` and `png` formats are more reliable though. The `ico` is still not working in 100% of the cases for me even when put inside the `public/images` folder (I tested using Next.js v13.3.1).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `next.js 13` you'll have to add `icons` field to `metadata` object in `app/layout.tsx`

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#icons