# Adding favicon in next js react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, favicon

I'm trying to add a favicon to a Next js project. The project was created using create-next-app.

I have a `favicon.png` in the `public` folder - Following the directions from static file serving [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

In my Layout file I have below code:

```
       <Head>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
          />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../public/favicon.png" />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          />
        </Head>
```

Layout file lives in a `components` directory and `public` is in the root.

However, the favicon is not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213019/how-to-add-a-favicon-to-a-next-js-static-site

Comment: I'm following exactly as mentioned there in the updated answer. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The favicon is loaded by browser and not during build time. You should specify the webroot directory.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
```

Comment: @Sooraj, what exactly error do you have? Does it say in a browser console/network tab that favicon is missing?

I believe that if you `favicon.ico` in `/public` and you reference to it like `/favicon.ico` in the tag it will work. You can create a new project with `create-next-app` and the default scaffolding already has favicon included.

However, I would assume that you don't see the favicon because it doesn't have type specified like `type="image/png"`

Comment: @Sooraj, I've updated the answer, try to specify `type="image/png"` and let me know if you have any errors

Answer (score 0):

In your example you do not need to move up a directory. Simply use `/public` instead of `../public`.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/public/favicon.ico" />`